# Spring Transactions - How to access to entity saved in parent transaction

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

consider following model:

```
@Service
public class TripServiceImpl implements TripService {

   @Autowired
   private EventService eventService;
   @Autowired
   private CalendarService calendarService;

   @Transactional
   public void processTrip(TripDto dto) {

       EventDto event = eventService.findByTripId(dto).orElseGet(() -> eventService.createByTrip(dto));
  
       dto.getMembers().forEach(memberCode -> {
           try {
              calendarService.createReminder(event.getId(), memberCode);
           } catch (Exception ex) {}
       });

       // rest logic
   }
}
```

This is how `createReminder` method looks like:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void createReminder(Long eventId, String memberCode) {
   Optiona<Event> eventRepository.findById(eventId); // this returns Optional.empty()
   ...
}
```

In our trip service we find or create event for given trip if no exists, and add reminders to calendars of members from that trip. Method for creating reminders we need as new transaction to ensure, if that method failed with exception, don't rollback all changes. This transaction propagation unfortunately can't find entity which was saved in parent transactional method. Can you tell me how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Due to transaction isolation, effect of surrounding transaction won't be visible in the child transaction unless the surrounding txn is committed. But if you nested transaction relies on the effect of surrounding transaction, you have a design issue here. Lets say your code worked as YOU expected. You would be in trouble if the reminders were added and committed but then event (surrounding transaction) got rolled back, i.e you have reminders for event that does not exist.

Comment: Actually from my understanding,  what you actually want is, you should run your `rest of the logic` in separate transaction and keep everything before that in one transaction. No nested transactions. I.e you don't mind about `rest of the logic` getting rolled back but your event and its reminders can succeed